# How to fix python program that appears to be doing an extra loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, while-loop

A portion of a python program I am writing seems to be looping an extra time. The part of the program that isn't working is below. It is supposed to ask for a string from the user and create a two-dimensional list where each distinct character of the string is put in its own sub-list. (Hopefully that makes sense... if not I can try to explain better. Perhaps the code will help)

```
def getInput(emptyList):
    inputString = input("Please enter a sentence:\n").strip().upper()
    functionList = [x for x in inputString]
    emptyList.extend(functionList)
    return 0

def sortList(listA,listB):
    listA.sort()
    currentElement = listA[0]
    compareTo = listA[0]
    elementsCounted = 0
    i = 0
    listB.append([])
    while elementsCounted  < len(listA):
        while currentElement == compareTo:
            listB[i].append(currentElement)
            elementsCounted += 1
            print(listB)
            if elementsCounted < len(listA):
                currentElement = listA[elementsCounted]
            else:
                break
        if currentElement != compareTo:
            i += 1
            listB.append([])
            compareTo = listA[i]

    return 0

def main():
    myList = list()
    sortedList = list()
    getInput(myList)
    sortList(myList,sortedList)
    print(sortedList)

main()
```

If the user enters `qwerty`, the program returns `[['E'], ['Q'], ['R'], ['T'], ['W'], ['Y']]` which is correct but if the user enters `qwwerrty` the program returns `[['E'], ['Q'], ['R', 'R'], [], ['T'], ['W', 'W'], [], ['Y']]`. Note the extra empty list after each "double" character. It appears that the loop is making one extra iteration or that the `if` statement before `listB.append([])` isn't written properly.

I can't seem to figure it out more than this. Thank you in advance for your help.

NOTE: `elementsCounted` should be a cumulative tally of each element that has been processed from listA. `i` is the index of the current element in listB. For example, if `['A','A','B']` was listA and the program is processing the second A, then it is the second element being counted but `i` is still 0 because it belongs in listB[0]. `currentElement` is the one currently being processed and it is being compared to the first element that was processed as that "i". For the `['A','A','B'] example, when processing the second A, it is being compared to the first A to see if`i`should be incremented. In the next loop, it is comparing 'B' to the first 'A' and thus will increase`i` by one since 'B' belongs in the next sub-list.

Comment: Why do you have separate `elementsCounted` and `i` variables? It looks like you always want `currentElement` and `compareTo` to be adjacent elements, but you're getting them out of sync. You should use a less error-prone way of iterating over elements in pairs. Google `Python iterate over list in pairs` to find some alternatives.

Comment: I've updated the question to try to explain the use of the variables. I will Google that and see what I can find.

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do can be achieved by using the ``itertools.Counter`` import. If you pass a string into it, you will get a dictionary of how many times each letter occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake lies in this part:

```
if currentElement != compareTo:
    ...
    compareTo = listA[i]
```

It should be:

```
if currentElement != compareTo:
    ...
    compareTo = listA[elementsCounted]
```

It's an overly complex function for such a simple task.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. On the note that it is more complex than need be, what would be a more simplistic approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simpler approach:

```
>>> def make_lists(inp):
...   i = 0
...   indices = {}
...   result = []
...   for c in sorted(inp):
...     if c not in indices:
...       result.append([c])
...       indices[c] = i
...       i += 1
...     else:
...       result[indices[c]].append(c)
...   return result
... 
>>> make_lists("qwerty")
[['e'], ['q'], ['r'], ['t'], ['w'], ['y']]
>>> make_lists("qwwerrty")
[['e'], ['q'], ['r', 'r'], ['t'], ['w', 'w'], ['y']]
>>>
```

Or if you want a one-liner:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [list(g) for _,g in itertools.groupby(sorted('qwwerrty'))]
[['e'], ['q'], ['r', 'r'], ['t'], ['w', 'w'], ['y']]
>>>
```

Comment: Upvote for edit. That was the solution I had in mind.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your solution. Currently, I'm a bit novice to Python to understand all of this but I certainly look forward to reaching that point! The conciseness of this is impressive. Unfortunately I cannot upvote because I am too new to Stack Overflow.